# Parsing Tables from a url with Htmlagility

Tags: c#, parsing, html-table, html-agility-pack, uwp

i m a beginner of C# and i m trying to learn how to get(extract) table data from a website with htmlagility, then show it in my app.

Any one knows why is .Load doesnt work?or it doesnt work only by UWP Coding?

The Compiler says that"HtmlWeb' does not contain a definition for 'Load' and no extension method 'Load' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Why is that and how to solve it?

```
public class  HtmlWeb{

public HtmlWeb()

{
    string Url = "http://google.de";

    HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();

    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = htmlWeb.Load(Url);
```

Thank u all X.L

Comment: You created your own `HtmlWeb` class, you should implement `Load()` method yourself...

Comment: I'm not sure if HtmlAgilityPack's `HtmlWeb` is available in UWP. If you want to try : [Can't use key functions on HTMLAgilityPack library (Visual Studio 2015 Community / UWP App)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4678ffab-5c3c-491d-af5f-3d8c974c3cd8/cant-use-key-functions-on-htmlagilitypack-library-visual-studio-2015-community-uwp-app?forum=csharpgeneral)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like was mentioned you will need to write your own `Load(string url)` function. I was bored and never heard of `HtmlAgilityPack` before so I mocked up something you can use. It reads the url http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp and finds all `<table>` nodes, then loops through them to find all `<td>` and `<th>` nodes. Then writes all the cells inner text to a page


Here is the aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication5.WebForm1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>HtmlAgilityPack quasi table parser</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Number of tables <asp:Literal ID="litNumTables" runat="server" /></h1>
    <strong>Each &lt;th&gt; and &lt;td&gt; node of each &lt;table&gt; [table][row][cell]</strong>
    <ul>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptTrNodes" Runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li>
                <%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebApplication5
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var html = new HtmlDocument();
            html.LoadHtml(new WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp"));
            var root = html.DocumentNode;
            var tableNodes = root.Descendants("table");
            var items = new List<string>();
            foreach(var tbs in tableNodes.Select((tbNodes,i) => new { tbNodes = tbNodes, i = i }))
            {
                items.Add(string.Format("<h2>&lt;table&gt; {0}<h2>", tbs.i));
                var trs = tbs.tbNodes.Descendants("tr");
                foreach(var tr in trs.Select((trNodes, j) => new { trNodes = trNodes, j = j }))
                {
                    var cellCounter = 0;
                    foreach(var cell in tr.trNodes.Descendants("th"))
                    {
                        items.Add(string.Format("&lt;th&gt; [{0}][{1}][{2}] - {3}", tbs.i, tr.j, cellCounter, cell.InnerText.Trim()));
                        cellCounter++;
                    }
                    foreach (var cell in tr.trNodes.Descendants("td"))
                    {
                        items.Add(string.Format("&lt;td&gt; [{0}][{1}][{2}] - {3}", tbs.i, tr.j, cellCounter, cell.InnerText.Trim()));
                        cellCounter++;
                    }
                }
            }
            litNumTables.Text = tableNodes.Count().ToString();
            rptTrNodes.DataSource = items;
            rptTrNodes.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

It should be pretty self explanatory but if it's what you are looking for, then I can explain further.

Comment: why was it downvoted, the code does what the user asked

Comment: hi @user3639090 i think UWP apps can't use "using System.Net;" and it causes 2 problems,which is 1,The type or namespace name 'Web' does not exist in the namespace 'System'  and 2, The type or namespace name 'WebClient' could not be found  do you know why and how to solve it thanx

Comment: If i wanna parse from this site [link](http://www.eurogymnasium-waldenburg.de/de/schuljahr/stunden-und-vertretungsplaene/2016-01-22-12-53-10) then could i use namespace 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' instead?cause system.web is not supported in UWP coding

Comment: i fixed 1.problem with using System.Net.Http.HttpClient，，but 2,is still there and i cant fix it

Comment: Honestly I don't know, never done any UWP programming. If you can't use the using System.Net, then you can just try System.Net.WebClient() instead of just WebClient()